# introduced to you/you to/for you/you for

Tags: grammar

> A: He has dated a lot of women.
>
> B: No, I haven't.
>
> C: How many has he introduced to you/you to/you for/for you?
>
> A: Three only this year. But he dumped them all.

If C is asking about how many girlfriends B has made A meet, which one of 'to you', 'you to', 'you for', and 'for you' would be correct?

Comment: Which one do _you_ think makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the first two options:

> How many has he introduced to you?

In this case, "how many [[girlfriends]]" is the direct object of "introduced". The girlfriends are being introduced to A.

> How many has he introduced you to?

In this case, the preposition does not precede its object. That is perfectly fine, but the syntax is easier to understand if we place it before its object:

> To how many has he introduced you?

Now we can see that "how many [[girlfriends]]" is the object of the preposition "to" and "you" is the direct object of "introduced". A is being introduced to the girlfriends.

The meanings of these two sentences are slightly different, but there is probably very little practical difference, since in both cases A and the girlfriends are meeting.

The preposition "for" has a different meaning and does not seem to achieve the result that you want here.